# Autosize textview is not working

Tags: android

Hi I am using autosize textview in my android application. My app minSdkVersion is 19 so I am using support library.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.android.registration.RegistrationActivity"
    tools:ignore="missingPrefix">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_registration_layout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_registration_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_medium"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/registration_title"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Does anyone know why it is not resizing as there is lot of space available on right side of it.

Comment: may not work sir, @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @UltimateDevil got the point . You should add static height

Comment: MyPleasure Sir, @IntelliJAmiya :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to a specific value

**Like :** `android:layout_height="200dp"`

You can read in documentation -:

**Note**: If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "`wrap_content`" for the `layout_width` or `layout_height` attributes of a `TextView`. It may produce unexpected results.

[image]

So, you must pass a fixed value to **`android:layout_height`** of **`TextView`**

Hope, this will help you

Comment: Maybe, but according to documentation for autosizing you must pass a fixed height

Comment: @Nancy, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjUdJ2aVqE4) may help you to understand

Answer (score 10):

In my case using only fixed dimension or match_parent didn't work. I had to add "maxLines=1" and "lines=1". Don't know why is this not made obvious in the documentation.

Comment: And remove "singleLine"==true if any!